# Server not recognizing special characters sent from client

Tags: javascript, .net, query-string, special-characters

In my C#.NET web application, using IE8, I'm using javascript to insert special characters (¿, «, ») into  a URL query string which will then be parsed by server code. However, the server does not seem to recognize these characters, and reads them as ��. My script tag appears as so:

```
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="UTF-8">
```

The following illustrates the jist of what I'm trying to accomplish, using javascript.

```
    window.open('../../CommonPages/Email.aspx?specialChar1=¿&specialChar2=«&specialChar3=»', 'EmailSearch', 'status=1,width=605,height=605,modal=1');
```

What am I missing? All help is greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Can you give us some more code than this? For one thing, the querystring is a very finicky beast, and it could very well be that the characters you're attempting to send are simply not compatible, as different browsers handle their URLs in different ways. I'd say that transferring such special characters through the querystring is tricky, at best, and potentially unreliable.

Comment: Did you check encoding at server side? I am from Java world and start the server with UTF-8 as encoding because the system encoding may be different. I agree with mori57's comment.